# Найти одно число в большой массе

Tags: математика, алгоритм, теория-вероятностей

*Продвинутая математика*, а тем более *Теория вероятностей* мне не знакомы.
Но я хотел бы получить детальные ответы именно на эти вопросы от знающих людей.

**Скажу так:**
У меня большая группа цифр от 1 до 1 с 50 нулями.  Вторая группа маленькая всего 1 миллиард. Именно эта группа находится внутри первой. Поясню: Представим что большая группа это один ряд кресел в театре! :-) А вторая группа миллиард человечков заняли места в этом ряду.

**И здесь 2 варианта:**
Один раз они сели выбрав случайные кресла.
А во второй раз один человек выбрал случайное место, а все остальные плотно (без пропусков) сели после него.
Теперь моя задача - найти хотя бы одно, занятое кресло - как в первом варианте, так и во втором. 
Я понимаю, что шансы резко возрастают во втором варианте, но на сколько??? Становится ли менее заоблочно что-то найти?
Можно сравнивать с лото 5 из 36. ))) Типа выиграть 5 номеров в 3х следующих тиражах.

**Как мне искать?**
Случайными цифрами или действовать наверняка 1 миллиард минус 1 начиная с одного и выше??? Но здесь одной жизни не хватит...

Comment: @moilenok77, я так и не понял что конкретно вам надо...

Comment: С математической точки зрения - как приблизится к решению этой задачки? И просчитать шансы успеха для двух вариантов.

Comment: На всякий уточню: вы не простые числа ищете? Вообще это как раз теория вероятностей, только я тоже ее не помню, но это не самая сложная задачка. Для расчета многократно повторяемых испытаний нужна [формула Бернулли](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8)

Comment: Нет, речь не идёт о простых числах. Они могут быть любыми, но в рамка большой группы.

Comment: надо на каждое кресло кнопку под попу поставить, чтобы когда туда кто-то садился, номер кресла сообщался в центр. :)

Comment: @moilenok77, для начала чисто технически решите вопрос с хранением этой **ОЧЕНЬ БОЛЬШОЙ группы**, а потом уже поговорим о поиске в ней.

Comment: OK для скептиков скажу:
Мне не надо хранить 10000...(50).
Мне достаточно взять любую цифру из этого ряда, зашифровать её и сравнить с цифрами из одного миллиарда.
Если совпало то ... это кресло)))

Comment: @moilenok77 скептикам ваша фраза не ясна. по пунктам - вы берете скажем  цифру 100, "шифруете ее" и что ? с чем сравниваем ?

Comment: @avp, возможно, данная задача поставлена, чтобы **не** хранить эту большую группу (не говоря уж о том, что хранение к вопросу не относится).

Comment: Ну это ведь не важно ;-) 
Практическая сторона не важна. Она отлично работает.
Вопрос скорее чисто теоретический который, как я понимаю может быть с лёгкостью подкреплён расчётами. Мне просто нужно видимости, чтоб кто то фонариком подсветил.
ГДЕ ВЫ ЗНАМЕНИТЫЕ МАТЕМАТИЧЕСКИЕ ГОЛОВЫ?

Comment: @moilenok77, Вы уверены, что *цифры* с *числами* не путаете?

Например, десятичные **цифры**:

      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

и все.

А шестнадцатиричные:


      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f


О каких цифрах (по какому основанию) Вы говорите?

Comment: @moilenok77 вот смотрите - ваша задача сводится к такой ? 

 1. вариант берем миллиард не повторяющихся случайных чисел в диапазоне от 1 до 10^50, записываем их в массив, и потом пытаемся угадать хотя-бы одно.
 2. вариант - берем одно случайное число N в диапазоне от 1 до 10^50 и пытаемся найти блок от N до N+10^9 

?  Если да, то я вам вот что скажу - случайным перебором, если запоминать уже "пустые" блоки или числа, не получится решать, ибо и в том и другом случае в вырожденном пределе вам придется запомнить 10^41 чисел, что мягко говоря за пределами ваших тех. возможностей.

Comment: Вероятность того, что вам действительно хватит памяти на такой перебор ,исходя из того что у вас скажем 100ТБ памяти доступно (без сжатия для простоты), вы можете посчитать сами. (одно число занимает у вас 21 байт)

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите.

В первом случае у вас не так много вариантов. Вы должны просто пробовать места одно за другим, запоминая уже выбранные. Например, в случайном порядке, или тупо подряд от первого к последнему. Перебирать придётся долго.

Во втором случае вы можете исключить из рассмотрения все номера, не кратные миллиарду. Таких номеров уже в миллиард раз меньше, но зато среди них и «выигрышный» номер всего один.

(По поводу оценки вероятности и среднего количества испытаний надо подумать...)

ЗЫ: А вообще-то, вопрос на [маткод](http://math.hashcode.ru/).